# How to select value of dropdown with ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, drop-down-menu

Here is my code and it's not selecting the value of the drop down list.

I tried many different ways but not working

```
<div class="container" style="height: 0;">
    <ul class="psh__dpdw ">
        <li class="button-dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle">
                 something <!-- here should be desplayed the dropdown-menu list when i click -->
                 <img src="{{theme_url}}/assets/images/arrow-down.png" alt="arrow-down">
            </a> {{ content:categories category_group_id="57" class="dropdown-menu" id=""}}
            <a href="{{helper:site_url}}something/{{category_id}}/{{url_title}}/{{category_id}}{{entry_id}}" name="alphabet">{{special}}</a> {{ /content:categories }}


            <!--<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <a href="prosecutor-pr.html">Soemthing</a>
                </li>
                
               
               
               
          </ul> -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script>
    $('.dropdown-menu li').find('a').change(function() {
        var dropdown = $(this).closest('.dropdown-toggle');
        var radioname = $(this).attr('name');
        var checked = 'a[name=' + radioname + ']:checked';

        //update the text
        var checkedtext = $(checked).closest('.dropdown-menu li').text();
        dropdown.find('a').text(checkedtext);

        //retrieve the checked value, if needed in page 
        var thisvalue = dropdown.find(checked).val();
        alert(thisvalue);

    });
</script>**
```

The button where you click on the drop-down menu, I want to display the value on the button part. Also, I am using the CMS code so, any suggestion?

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get `container` div using [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and use find to get `dropdown-toggle` using  [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find).

And also you have used wrong method for `a` tag, you need to use [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) instead of change like this

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function() {});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function() {
  var dropdown = $(this).closest(".container").find('.dropdown-toggle');
  dropdown.text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="height: 0;">
  <ul class="psh__dpdw ">
    <li class="button-dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle">
        <img src="{{theme_url}}/assets/images/arrow-down.png" alt="arrow-down">
      </a> {{ content:categories category_group_id="57" class="dropdown-menu" id=""}}
      <a href="{{helper:site_url}}prokuroria_themelore/{{category_id}}/{{url_title}}/{{category_id}}{{entry_id}}" name="alphabet">{{special}}</a> {{ /content:categories }}
      <br><br>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Prishtinë</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Gjilan</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Prizren</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Pejë</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Mitrovicë</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Gjakovë</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Ferizaj</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```